# addEventListener.delay() can be doable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qualtrics

Hi I have a code in qualtrics written with jquery. I need to implement delay function for event listening. My code enables key press as inputs. there should be a delay function...

I should disable the keys for the first 2000ms then enable them.

My task has 3 different parts and all parts are dipslayed or hid according to the time.

so here is my code;

```
function disableMouse(event) {
  event.stopPropagation()
}
window.disableMouseFunction = disableMouse


Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {

  document.body.style.cursor = 'none'; // hide cursor

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function keydownCallback(e) {
      var that = this;
      var aa = null;
      switch (e.keyCode) {

        case 37: // left arrow key                 
          that.setChoiceValue(1, true) //pic a     
          aa = 1;
          break;

        case 39: // right arrow key                  
          that.setChoiceValue(2, true) //pic B     
          aa = 1;
          break;
      }
      if (aa) {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', keydownCallback, true);
        //move to the next page after delay
        that.clickNextButton();
      }
    });
  }, 1000);
});

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('#showfirst').delay(500).hide(1);
    jQuery('#hideafter').delay(500).show(1);
    jQuery('#hideafter').delay(2000).hide(1);
    jQuery('#reveallater').delay(2550).show(2);
  })
});
```

Comment: delay for event listening? no clue what that means

Comment: @epascarello I have 3 different steps in my task, participants need to see all of them. but if they accidentally press a key before the task ends, they proceed to the next page. So I need to disable keys for first 2000ms

Comment: Why not disable the input itself for the 2 first seconds?

Comment: Have it disabled from the start, and then use a setTimeout to enable it after 2 seconds.

Comment: So why don't you add code inside the event handler to see if the task is done? Seems like that makes more sense than random timers

Comment: @epascarello thanks! I will try it!

Comment: @some how can I do that? I could not dısable them from the start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not disable the input for first 2 seconds, so I just hide the choices and make them appear after 2 seconds. People do not try to answer when the selections are not visible. Not the perfect solution but it works.

```
<style> .QuestionBody { display: none;} </style> //in qualtrics
```

This can be a helpful trick for those who have similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to listen to the document, since there is no `input` at all in [this](https://utdallas.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_bsaRXWZ9gJcy5Fj)...

I have you a function for that, have a try.

```js
function disableSurveyArrows(delay){  // delay is in seconds
  var ArrowsDisabled = true;

  setTimeout(function(){
    ArrowsDisabled = false;
    $("#onoff").html("Arrows enabled now.")
  },5000);


  $(document).on("keydown",function(e){
    console.clear();
    if(ArrowsDisabled){
      console.log(".");
      return false;
    }
    if(e.which==37){
      console.log("Left");
    }
    if(e.which==39){
      console.log("Right");
    }
  });
}

// Call the function. 5 seconds is passed here.
disableSurveyArrows(5);
```

```css
span{
  margin:calc(25% - 50px);
}
#onoff{
  font-size:4em;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span style="font-size:100px">←</span><span style="font-size:100px">→</span>
<div id="onoff">Arrows disabled</div>
```

Comment: I tried but since I am using qualtrics and its own input system I cannot disable it like that

Comment: There certainly is an id or class you could use.

Comment: I made a function for you to try... ;)